# Why does the resolve message appear first?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to wrap my mind around promises in JavaScript. I was under the illusion that once a Promise was resolved it could never go back to rejected. To test that I wrote a little script. I see that the first messages that come back are the resolve messages "1 resolve 2" etc. I expected the first message to be "0 reject 1".

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let a = 1 + (i % 2)

        if (a === 2) {
            resolve(i + ' resolve ' + a)
        } else {
            reject(i + ' reject ' + a)
        }       
    })

    p.then((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    }).catch((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    })
}
```

at the console:

```
[Log] 1 resolve 2
[Log] 3 resolve 2
[Log] 5 resolve 2
[Log] 7 resolve 2
[Log] 9 resolve 2
[Log] 0 reject 1
[Log] 2 reject 1
[Log] 4 reject 1
[Log] 6 reject 1
[Log] 8 reject 1
< Promise {status: "pending"}
```

thanks for you help....

After reading

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

I got to this code. The catch is removed.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let a = 1 + (i % 2)

    if (a === 2) {
        resolve(i + ' resolve ' + a)
    } else {
        reject(i + ' reject ' + a)
    }

})

p.then((message) => {
    console.log(message)
}, failed => {
    console.log(failed)
}) 
}
```

at the console:

```
[Log] 0 reject 1
[Log] 1 resolve 2
[Log] 2 reject 1
[Log] 3 resolve 2
[Log] 4 reject 1
[Log] 5 resolve 2
[Log] 6 reject 1
[Log] 7 resolve 2
[Log] 8 reject 1
[Log] 9 resolve 2
< Promise {status: "pending"}
```

Comment: You are creating new promise on every iteration

Comment: You have 10 promises, they don't "go back to rejected" like you said.

Comment: Is your question why you see the resolved promises before the rejected? I.e. why is the output [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8] instead of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]?

Comment: Yes Junvar. That is my question.

Comment: 99% sure it's because the `.then` and `.catch` each take a tick on the event loop. So the rejections are all a single tick behind your resolves.

Comment: I'd add that 1% to that.

Answer (score 4):

You can see what's going on under the hood by using your the console of your browser's dev tools and, possibly, setting break points (this articles might be helpful if u're using [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)):

[image]

As you can see, all your 10 promises are created before any of them are executed (resolve/reject).

Interestingly, in your code the resolved promises are handled first.

If you define the handlers in two separate definitions, you'll get the expected results:

```
p.then((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    })
p.catch((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    })
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i am so surprize by the conclusion of your answer. I never imagined than chain vs multiple instruction can have this huge impact. Really good sharing

Answer (score 2):

The point is, Promises are made to be used as Asynchronous calls, so when you execute your loop and for each iteration you creates a new promise, you are creating new instances, and each one of those can be executed in their own time.

But what this even means? The explanation is, when you create 10 new Promises in a loop, each promise will be executed in his own time and probablly will mess up with your promise solving order.

What you can do to solve it? You can use `await` command to wait each promise to solve, like the code bellow:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let a = 1 + (i % 2)

        if (a === 2) {
            resolve(i + ' resolve ' + a)
        } else {
            reject(i + ' reject ' + a)
        }       
    })

    await p.then((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    }).catch((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    })
}
```

Or you could try use `Promise.all()` which will basically solve the order for you, see the official [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all)

Comment: well, you can remove the `.then` if you're using `await`

Comment: Yes I could use async-await; and do prefer that. It's that I want to get to understand the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript are mono thread :

- promise
- eventListener
- setTimeout
- setInterval

previous listed method are not part of javascript enterpreter (V8 Engine for example), it delegate to the **event loop** which are part of browser or nodejs. *[more information here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4)*

Basically this code are delegate to 3th party (node, browser) which will decide himself when and on which order this collection of [microtasks](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#solitary-callback-microtasks) will be executed and return to the main thread.

is Why Following code :

```js
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('micro task thread');
    });

    p.then((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    }).catch((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    });
    console.log('main thread');
```

will print "main thread" then "micro task thread" but you don't have any obvious delayed code. Is because all main thread function call will be execute before doing task on eventLoop.

Most of the time, event loop will execute the collection as first come first rendered.

Comment: @Edwin i have not understand what you try to say. Ludovico post interesting answer. And my answer contain, i think, some tips to understand how async traitment work under the hood.

Comment: Fair question. Yes you gave a good explanation of how the event loop works and how promise fits in there. Ludvico posted a solution that produced the expected result.That still did not explain to me enough why it was happening. The key to understanding this was at MDN saying: The catch() is calling Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onrejected). Then I looked at the description of then Promise.prototype.then(). Under the syntax header I found this.

Comment: you can see much mind blown with following case :  [all case posted here :o](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nt1rxj)

Answer (score 0):

I did found a solution here:
[MDN promise then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let a = 1 + (i % 2)

        if (a === 2) {
            resolve(i + ' resolve ' + a)
        } else {
            reject(i + ' reject ' + a)
        }
    })

    p.then((message) => {
        console.log(message)
    }, failed => {
        console.log(failed)
    }) 
}
```

promise.catch() is calling promise.then(undefined, onreject). That is why resolve allways appeared first.

Comment: I will note that though this is absolutely valid, most developers will never wrote code like that (and some would probably be confused as to it's behavior).